# How to use Susy2 with Compass / SASS?

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, susy-compass

I'm trying to figure out how to get Susy2 working alongside compass on my local system, and I've been all over trying to find the answer.

```
 error sass/screen.scss (Line 4 of sass/_base.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: susy.
    Load paths:
      /Users/jem/Desktop/base/sass
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.0.alpha.21/stylesheets
      /Users/jem/.compass/extensions/compass-normalize/stylesheets
      /Users/jem/.compass/extensions/compass-recipes-master/stylesheets
      /Users/jem/.compass/extensions/toolkit/stylesheets
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sassy-maps-0.4.0/sass
      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/breakpoint-2.4.2/stylesheets
      Compass::SpriteImporter
      Sass::Globbing::Importer)
    ArgumentError on line ["161"] of /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.3.3/lib/sass/error.rb: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
    Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

I hit this error continually (although occasionally for other gems as well). I feel like I've tried every combination of installing and uninstalling gems, ruby, bundler, etc.

Instructions continually point me toward:

1. Using Bundler to manage the gems (I am).
2. Make sure *require "susy"* is in my config.rb (Yup.)
3. Make sure I'm on the new alpha version of compass (using 1.0.0.alpha.20)

I'm not having any luck, and I can only assume it's something going on with my local system (OS 10.9, using Ruby 2.1.2 with RVM to stay separate from the system ruby). I had susy working once on a separate linux box, but when I brought the code here I keep running into these susy issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bundler, your Gemfile should include:

```
gem "susy", "~>2.1.0"
gem "sass", "~>3.3.0"
gem "breakpoint", "~>2.4.0"
```

Bundler should set up all the other dependencies you need.

Since you are using RVM for your Ruby installation, are you sure that you are using the default Ruby (as per RVM) or the system Ruby which might be only Ruby 1.8.7 (rather than Ruby 2.0)?

Comment: Yup, got all that too, as I've been hoping to use the latest version of susy. Bundle install takes care of the initial installation, bundle update updates things if I add or change a gem. And I'm on ruby 2.1.2 installed through RVM and confirmed via "rvm list" or "which ruby".

Comment: I'm starting to believe that my ruby environment is borked somewhere.

This same issue came up trying to work with "toolkit" and "normalize" compass extensions as well. ("File to import not found or unreadable" error, even though it appears to be installed and required correctly, and I can even find the file path within my system and gem lists). The susy gem would be in the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ folder along side the others but it still doesn't work. 

Totally stumped as to how to fix it. I've tried reinstalling rvm / additional rubys, but no luck yet.